# Mysql2 error in NextJS13, cant find module Net

Tags: javascript, next.js, mysql2

I'm trying to acquire information from a mysql database in nextjs13 using the mysql2 dependency, like this:

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise'

export const getData = async(req, res) => {
    const dbconnection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: "hostname",
        database: "databasename",
        user: "username",
        password: "password",

      });

      try {
        const query = "SELECT productid, productname, productimage FROM products";
        const values = [];
        const [data] = await dbconnection.execute(query, values);
        dbconnection.end();
    
        res.status(200).json({ products: data });
      } catch (error) {
        // unhide to check error
        // res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
      }

  return dbconnection
}
```

At first the error was that the net module was missing, which is called when mysql.createConnection is used. Then when I added the module, it said that net.connection is not a function. I have already tried it in both client side and server side components and neither work. The strings in the object are examples ofc. Does anybody know what could it be?